# What does the syntax of these echo commands mean?

Tags: linux, shell-script, tcsh

I tried to use a copied script, which includes the following command

```
echo "rc  $2" > $WORKDIR/out.dat
```

I can guess it tries to output some contents to file out.dat. But what does `rc $2` mean?

It also includes

```
echo "PWD" >> $WORKDIR/env.txt
```

Why does it use `>>` here instead of `>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of these are actually `echo` questions.

`"rc $2"` is the text "rc", a space, and the second argument passed to the script or function.

`>>` appends to an existing file, as opposed to `>` which writes to a new file, erasing any existing file in the process.